# Hibernate - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.SampleProjectDto.UserDetails cannot be cast to com.splwg.base.api.GenericPersistentEntity

Tags: java, hibernate

I was trying to write my first Hibernate project, while running it I got this exception:
 **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.SampleProjectDto.UserDetails cannot be cast to com.splwg.base.api.GenericPersistentEntity**
Table got created in the DB but values are not inserted in it.

**Model class:**

```
package com.SampleProjectDto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
@Id
private int userId;
private String UserName;


public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}


}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@(db_details)</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>    
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class ="com.SampleProjectDto.UserDetails"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Main Class:**

```
    package com.hibernate.test;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

    import com.SampleProjectDto.UserDetails;

    public class HibernateTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Somya");

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    ServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory(srb.buildServiceRegistry());
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

}
```

**Error Log:**

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.SampleProjectDto.UserDetails cannot be cast to com.splwg.base.api.GenericPersistentEntity
at org.hibernate.event.internal.COBOLCompatibleFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(COBOLCompatibleFlushEntityEventListener.java:136)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:225)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1127)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:325)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at com.hibernate.test.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:25)
```

Would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

I extended **GenericPersistentEntity** class, now its working fine.